# Opening a window in the background using Enlightenment Elementary toolkit

Tags: c++, background, window, efl

I want to open a webview in the background when other webview is already on the stack. Is it even possible in EFL? Every attempt finishes with some kind of crash. Maybe you have any hints how to to something like that?

Comment: How are you attempting to open it - from within the webview or from a containing application? What sort of crashes have you been encountering and what API were you using when you saw the crash?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by background?
I guess you meant "thread".

You can do other jobs and heavy calculations in another thread with EFL apps but it is not possible to call "EFL APIs(including webview)" directly inside a thread.
If you want to create a webview while doing something else, use ecore_idler or ecore_idle_enterer.
ecore_idler is called when there is nothing to do - no event, no touch, no timer expiration, and etc.
ecore_idle_enterer is called right before the every rendering. So it is guaranteed that it is called at least once at a loop.

Thanks.